# Force create handle for Control

Tags: c#, controls, handle

I'm currently creating a silent print module. The current control I'm using is, it's making sure that the control handle is already created (`IsHandleCreated`). I did everything to cheat this with no luck at all.

Do you have ideas in mind on how can I create a handle for the control without displaying any in the screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to overload `CreateParams` property getter. In it clear the `WS_VISIBLE` flag.

Comment: I found that this.CreateHandle(); works really well (from within the form)

Answer (score 23):

You have to access the **Handle** property (put the result in a dummy variable or something). Look in Reflector; it forces handle creation.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with some other controls and used the [`Control.CreateControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.createcontrol.aspx) method:

```
private void CheckForExistingHandle(Control control)
{
    if (!control.IsHandleCreated)
        control.CreateControl();
}
```

But i don't know how it works with a print module.

Comment: Make sure the control's visible property is set to true, or the handle won't be created from a `CreateControl()` call. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.createhandle%28v=VS.90%29.aspx for more informations.

Comment: @Drahakar That's a very good note: `CreateControl` might choose not to create the control. The workaround noted on MSDN is to access the `.Handle` property

Answer (score 0):

I solved this annoying handle creation problem by settings the WS_VISIBLE of CreationParams. You may either override the CreationParams property of Control or call the CreateHandle method with appropriate CreateParams instance. See the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.handle.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Calling private method CreateHandle will do the work.

```
MethodInfo ch = frm.GetType().GetMethod("CreateHandle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
ch.Invoke(frm, new object[0]);
```